# Install ROS Kinetic with Anaconda/Miniconda

Tags: ros, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to install ROS Kinetic but I need Anaconda. When I run catkin_make I get the following error

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/kalvik/miniconda3/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/kalvik/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/kalvik/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/kalvik/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263430/install-ros-kinetic-with-anaconda/miniconda/) by [kalvik](https://answers.ros.org/users/30679/kalvik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

to use Anaconda you will need to do a lot with your PYTHONPATH to make sure that all dependencies are on the path that Anaconda's interpreter is using.

I would recommend trying to find a way to use anaconda separately/in parallel with your anaconda installation. The main problem is that Anaconda doesn't use the standard installed python libraries so often you end up with missing resources.

I'd recommend searching for other questions about anaconda on this site. Here's a quick sampling:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/222992/ros-jade-using-anaconda-python-on-os-x/?answer=223000#post-id-223000
- https://answers.ros.org/question/244644/conflict-with-ros-python-and-conda/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/253683/error-while-trying-to-create-workspace-with-catkin_make/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/243261/rosrun-rqt_graph-rqt_graph-import-error-no-module-named-rospkgis-this-is-related-to-anaconda/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/159416/rospack-depends1-error-rosdep-version/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0